# How to create Asymmetric Grid layout like this?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

How to create Asymmetric Grid layout like this using RecyclerView or GridView in Android Java only?

Note: The data comes in from an online database, so I want the column width to be adjusted according to the size of its content.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in using `FlexboxLayout` https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout.